# Animating ellipsis in XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, animation, ellipsis

Imagine some text:

```
<TextBlock>Loading...</TextBlock>
```

I'd like a simple animation of the ellipsis (the `...` characters) where it oscillates between `.`, `..` and `...` in a slow cycle in order to give the impression that something's happening.

Is there a simple way to do this in XAML for WPF?

Comment: And lie about the UI actually being aware of the loading process? Let's see if I can think of something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A pure XAML solution might look like this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Duration="0:0:3" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Loading."/>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="Loading.."/>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="Loading..."/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </TextBlock.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after and it works perfectly. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you need something you can sandbox and play with.

```
class LoadingElipsis : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public LoadingElipsis()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(this.Spin);
        thread.Start();
    }

    public string Display
    {
        get
        {
            switch(DateTime.Now.Second % 3)
            {
                default: return "Loading.";
                case 1: return "Loading..";
                case 2: return "Loading...";
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Spin()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Notify("Display");
        }
    }

    protected void Notify(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

And the XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <project:LoadingElipsis x:Key="loading" />
</Window.Resources>    
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=loading}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Display}" Background="Red"/>
</Grid>
```

Disclamer:
Not a full example, with a formal background thread that can cancel, but with some effort you can get it to report information back from what you're loading, etc.

For those scenarios where a simple XAML animation isn't enough.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest to use a timer (preferably a DispatcherTimer) instead of a Thread with Sleep.

Comment: I agree, this was just to get it off the ground.
The only reason to use this approach over the key frame animation is if you have to set it in code or have a more dynamic effect.
Using this (without the sleep), gives you the ability to post meaningful updates like % complete, etc.